# avisynth - video framerate doesn't match (AssumeFPS - ChangeFPS)

Tags: video, video-editing, avisynth

I am trying to speed up only certain frames in a video without splitting it into several parts, here is the code that I used to do this

```
AVISource("C:\Users\me\Desktop\source_10FPS.avi")   # get the 10 fps video source

b= Trim(0,100)                                       # trim the first 10  seconds
a= Trim(100,200).AssumeFPS(14, sync_audio=TRUE)      # trim and speed it up 
c= Trim(200,0).AssumeFPS(10, 1, true)                #trim and go back to original speed 
return (a+b+c)                                       # combine the 3 Trims
```

but I get a "`video framerate doesn't match`" error

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you use conacatenation of clips then you have to provide the same format and framerate for each clip in concatenation chain

Comment: thank you for your answer but I got an answer here and it did the job http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502319/avisynth-video-framerate-doesnt-match